# Display the checkboxes in the console using java

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, checkbox, pdfbox

I have many pdf files and I need to extract the entire test from those files and display it in the console. I can do that easily using PDF box and I was able to print that in console. But some files have many checkboxes for e.g it displays frequency: []1year []monthly []3 years like this way and one of the boxes is crossed(checked).
But the problem is in console its showing like this:
frequency:  1year  monthly  3years
the checkboxes are not getting printed. I have searched everywhere and all are showing how to create a checkbox but I dont need that. I just want to display it and then I have to find out what is the frequency. How to do that? Given here is my code to extract pdf data:-

```
PDDocument doc=PDDocument.load(file);

PDTextStripper pdfStripper=new PDTextStripper();

String text=pdStripper.getText(doc);

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Do a proper reformatting of the code snippet so that it can be easily visible. Look out for https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try this https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.PDF-for-Java/Program-Guide/Form-Fields/Read-and-Extract-Fillable-Form-Values-in-PDF-in-Java.html

Comment: Likely acroform fields. Try the `PrintFields.java` example in the source code download.